# JavaScript form validation removes values

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, npm

I am using a JavaScript library for client-side form validation (https://github.com/cferdinandi/bouncer). It works very well but has one strange behaviour that I don't understand.

I have two buttons for the form submit, each with a different value. Without validating this form using the library I will retrieve the exact value on server-side. But when I use the library for validation the value will disappear. All other form values are available. I checked the whole library code and found out that "event.preventDefault()" seems to be the problem.

When I remove this line everything is fine but of course, form validation won't work.

Someone has any idea?

```
var submitHandler = function (event) {

            // Only run on matching elements
            if (!event.target.matches(selector)) return;

            // Prevent form submission
            event.preventDefault();

            // Validate each field
            var errors = publicAPIs.validateAll(event.target);

            // If there are errors, focus on the first one
            if (errors.length > 0) {
                errors[0].focus();
                emitEvent(event.target, 'bouncerFormInvalid', {errors: errors});
                return;
            }

            // Otherwise, submit if not disabled
            if (!settings.disableSubmit) {
                event.target.submit();
            }

            // Emit custom event
            if (settings.emitEvents) {
                emitEvent(event.target, 'bouncerFormValid');
            }

        };
```

```
<button class="" name="page[__page]" type="submit" value="0">back</button>
<button class="" name="page[__page]" type="submit" value="2">next</button>
```

Comment: Probably because you're submitting the form using `event.target.submit();` and not from the click event (But I'm not sure about that - never used this library)

Comment: @Alan. That Code Snippet ist from the Library. When I remove event.preventDefault() there is no problem, the button values will be send within the form.

Comment: According to the comment `event.preventDefault()` is there to prevent form submission. so that seems to be desired behavior. Maybe you should specify what you mean with "value", or maybe add the code of your form if possible

Comment: @ndreising I have a typical <form> with several inputs for name, street, age. When submitting and form is valid, all input values will be send to the server. But not the value of the clicked button (example in my post). But when I disable the validation library the value of the clicked button will be send to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, [accordingly to standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-the-form-data-set), seems to be that the submitter is not forwarded, when `.submit()` is invoked:

> If any of the following is true:
>
> - The field element is a button **but it is not submitter**.
>
> Then continue.

This case seems to be resolvable moving that information into an hidden field, and use the submitter, which is either `next`, or `prev`, to populate its value.

Example

```
document.body.innerHTML = `
  <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="page[__page]">
    <button class="" type="submit" value="0">back</button>
    <button class="" type="submit" value="2">next</button>
  </form>
`;

document.body.firstElementChild.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var page = e.target.querySelector('input[name="page[__page]"]');
  page.value = e.submitter.value;
  e.target.submit();
});
```

At this point, the page will be passed around as expected, and your issue should be resolved.

P.S. you could also explore [form.repostValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) and use `e.preventDefault()` only if the report returns `false`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I solved it exactly that way. I just wanted to understand the problem.

Comment: then I guess you can flag it as the answer, 'cause the explanation is in how standards work when the submitter is involved in a manual submit.